# Explicitly violate type system in C++ using arrays?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Bjarne Stroustrup's *The Design and Evolution of C++*, and in section 4.4 he states:

> C++ inherits features from C, such as unions, casts, and **arrays**, that make it impossible to detect every violation at compile time. Currently, C++ does not admit implicit violation of the type system. That is, you need to explicitly use a union, cast, **array**, an explicitly unchecked function argument, or explicitly unsafe C linkage to break the system.

Every way to violate the type system he listed makes sense to me except for the one on arrays. For example:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Point points[5];
    points[0] = 5;   // Type mismatch compile error
}
```

This code works as I expect it to, throwing a compile error for trying to assign an `int` to an array of `Points`. What is Stroustrup referring to when he says that arrays can be used to violate the type system?

Comment: He's probably referring to array decay to a pointer.  And as a parameter, unable to distinguish between "a pointer to a thing" and "a pointer to an array of things".  Also possibly the downstream loss of the size of an array.

Comment: @Eljay Should be "a pointer to the first thing of an array" instead of "a pointer to an array of things." Still +1, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be decaying contexts.
let's have an array whose elements' type is `T` as example.

```
T arr[5];
```

arr's type is, obviously, `T[5]`.

But in fact, in many contexts, `arr` is used to construct a pointer prvalue, pointing to the first element of the array, then it's type implicitly cast to `T*`.

this process is what we call *decay*.

decay takes place very common. The judging method is that in any context a pointer is required,  the array decays to pointer.

You said that your code worked as you expected, but a decay indeed happened, in the *subscript expression*, where complier replaced it with `*(Points + 0)`, and `Points` is decayed. However, It's so subtle that we can hardly feel it.

[here](https://ideone.com/Pt5gyE) you can experience how do arrays decay.

in your code, the complier throw complier error **only** because there's no implicit conversion from `Point` to `int`, and have absolutely no relation to arrays.